# Cross Thread Operation Not Valid C# Winform

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm trying to make an Application (similar to whatsapp), well everything is implemented but when ever i try to update any GUI component is give me exception i searched and found we should check invokeRequired and invoke it accordingly this is my code but still the exception is there.

```
 delegate void statuss(string str);
    void showstatus(string str)
    {

        metroLabel2.Visible = true;
        metroLabel2.Text = "Status: " + str;
    }
    private void Wa_OnGetStatus(string from, string type, string name, string status)
    {
        statuss get = new statuss(showstatus);
        get(status);
        if (metroLabel2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(get, metroLabel2, status);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Need the exception ToString. Also the if check makes no sense as it stands. if it's false you just do nothing. That's a bug. Do you *understand* the invoke pattern? Copying code without understanding is error prone.

Comment: Because you call "get(status)" before checking InokeRequired. So if you need to marshall to the UI thread first you are still invoking from the wrong thread. Code should be something like:   private void Wa_OnGetStatus(string from, string type, string name, string status)
    {
        statuss get = new statuss(showstatus);
        if (metroLabel2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(get, metroLabel2, status);
        }else {get(status);
        }

    }

Comment: Yes i understand it takes a delegate with an array of arguments to invoke. Thanks mate :)
Yes i tried your way and it seems to work now i understand :)